# Full-screen photos for incoming calls in iOS7.1

Tags: iphone, ios

I have upgraded my iPhone to iOS 7.1 What the hell happened to my full-screen photos for  incoming calls?

Comment: What do you possibly expect anyone to answer to a "question" (using the term loosely) like this?

Comment: Ehh yes, and we all have to know what it looks right now and how it looked before in the past? Maybe screenshots an option? Or at least more details?

Answer (score 2):

Apple changed the layout/design of the incoming-call and call-in-progress screen with iOS 7.1. If you want to let them know that you preferred the old layout, you can use the [Apple Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) form on apple.com.